# Error instalar Urllib2 desde terminal: ERROR:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib2

Tags: python

Estoy intentando installar urllib2 desde la terminal usando el comando:

```
pip install urllib2
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente

> ERROR:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib2
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib2

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Resumiendo:

**No necesitas instalar `urllib2` en absoluto.**

`urllib2` era un paquete incluido en Python 2. En Python 3 ese mismo paquete se separó en varias partes. Según la propia [documentación](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> The `urllib2` module has been split across several modules in Python 3
> named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`.

Comento esto porque si te has visto en la necesidad de instalar `urllib2` sospecho que estás intentando trabajar con algo pensado para Python 2 en Python 3.

De ser así tienes varias opciones:

- utilizar `urllib.request` en lugar de `urllib2`
- utilizar el paquete `requests`
- migrar tu script de Python 2 a Python 3 con [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#to3-reference)

Opciones que **NO** deberías plantearte:

- Utilizar Python 2